# Content inside <p> tag in Wikipedia isn't displayed

Tags: google-chrome

Content inside `<p>` tag in English Wikipedia page isn't displayed in Chrome. There is no problem with the pages in other languages or while using other browsers.
How can I solve this problem?

I'm using Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit) and macOS 10.12.5.

Here are screenshots of Wikipedia:

#### Chrome

[image: english wikipedia, chrome]

#### Safari

[image: english wikipedia, safari]

Comment: Try 1/ Reinstalling chrome 2/ Disabling extensions 3/ Using a new profile

Comment: @DavidPostill Using a new profile fixes the problem! Is it because of extensions?

Comment: It seems that AdBlock extension causes this problem!!!